# How can I keep track of database schema changes when using raw sql?

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

I have decided for my project to use raw sql queries instead of using an ORM, such as sequelize, to give me more control over my queries. Plus I just prefer writing raw sql queries.

I am wondering what is the best way to keep track of my DB schema changes so I can easily rollback if need be? I can't seem to find any packages which do just this.

Comment: What do you mean "migrations?"  take a backup beforehand.

Comment: @OldProgrammer I'm used to using ORMs where there's `up` and `down` functions which can be executed on the command line to execute queries or rollback. I was just wondering whether packages like that existed without using a full-blown ORM, as I find them quite useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By migrations I assume you mean schema changes.

There are packages that help to track schema changes, even if you are not using an ORM. Here are a few:

- [Flyway](https://flywaydb.org)
- [Liquibase](https://www.liquibase.org)
- [Skeema](https://www.skeema.io/download/)

Stack Overflow is not supposed to be a place for product recommendations. We can't guess at which of these products will be best for your needs. So I encourage you to read about each of them and try them out, and see which one is best for you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I clearly had the wrong term whilst searching so was unable to find anything.